# multi-line export without a newline

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, newlines

How can I export something that's multiline?

```
export foo='bar  a ab          ai   ii              bar'
```

and put that on two different lines without a newline literal?

```
export foo='bar  a ab          ai 
  ii              bar'
```

perhaps with a backslash?

```
export foo='bar  a ab          ai\ 
  ii              bar'
```

is this safe?

Comment: In the end, do you want `$foo` to contain one or two lines (0 or 1 newline characters)?

Comment: I don't want any newlines yeah

Answer (score 2):

Using `\` within a single-quote block clearly doesn't work.

```
$ export foo='bar  a ab          ai\
  ii              bar'
$ echo "$foo"
bar  a ab          ai\
  ii              bar
```

You could use double quotes.

```
$ export foo="bar  a ab          ai\
  ii              bar"
$ echo "$foo"
bar  a ab          ai  ii              bar
```

Or you could put it outside of the single quotes.

```
$ export foo='bar  a ab          ai'\
'  ii              bar'
$ echo "$foo"
bar  a ab          ai  ii              bar
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "safe".

Comment: by safe means always works

Comment: @AlexanderMills What specifically do you mean by "always works"? This will always work for two strings.